# Laravel validation: two chain conditions

Tags: php, laravel

i have four textboxes (textbox_1, textbox_2, textbox_3, textbox_4).

if textbox_4 is empty i need to check if textbox_2 and textbox_3 are not empty , then i need to require textbox_1 to not empty.

please help me do this inside the App\Http\Request\MyFormRequests.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please ignore, solved:

```
$rules = [ 'previous_fields' => 'require' ];

if ($this->textbox_4 =='')
{
   $rules['textbox_1'] = 'required_with_all:textbox_2,textbox_3';
}

return $rules;
```

Comment: i didn't know you can put **if** statements inside **public function rules()** (smile)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `required_without_all` for this. Check the [official Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-required-without-all).

From the documentation:

> The field under validation must be present only when all of the other specified fields are not present.

Comment: if 4 is empty ONLY then i need to check 2 and 3 to not empty in order to check 1 to not empty. thank you anyway.